# When is the index.hbs loaded in an Ember app? What is the difference between a component and a template?

Tags: ember.js

I was following this Ember tutorial and this quickly got a lot more complicated. This was the [tutorial](http://thetechcofounder.com/getting-started-with-ember-js-using-ember-cli/) that I was following.

I am lost as to what is going on. When is the index.hbs getting loaded and why? Here is my code starting with the router.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todos', { path: '/'}, function() {
    this.route('complete');
    this.route('incomplete');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

So it looks like our home url will load the todos.js route right? This is my code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let todos = [
      {
        title: 'Learn Ember',
        complete: false,
      },
      {
        title: 'Solve World Hunger',
        complete: false,
      }
    ];
    return todos;
  }
});
```

So this todos.js route is my model right?

I assume ember also loads the todos.hbs template by default? Is that right? Or does it load the app/templates/todos/index.hbs? Which one does it load?

This is my app/templates/todos.hbs code:

```
<input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
{{#todo-list todos=model}}
    {{outlet}}
{{/todo-list}}
```

This is my app/templates/todos/index.hbs code:

```
<ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each model as |todo|}}
         <!-- this loads the component todo-item and passes in a todo as todo -->
        {{todo-item todo=todo}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The tutorial doesn't really explain what is going on here. If the index.hbs gets loaded, does it then load the todo-item component template? If so, this is my app/templates/components/todo-item.hbs:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" checked="{{if todo.complete 'checked'}}">  
<label class="{{if todo.complete 'completed'}}">{{todo.title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
```

In the event that the app/templates/todos.hbs gets loaded...What is going on in the app/templates/todos.hbs? Are we passing in the model (somehow accessible in the template?) as todos to the todo-list component? Here is the app/templates/components/todo-list.hbs

```
<section id="main">
    {{yield}}

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all">
</section>

<footer id="footer">
    <span id="todo-count">
        <strong>2</strong> todos left
    </span>
    <ul id="filters">
        <li>
            <a href="all" class="selected">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="active">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="completed">Completed</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button id="clear-completed">
        Clear completed (1)
    </button>
</footer>
```

Comment: You have a lot of questions here. I think several of them can be answered by [the Ember routing guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing), specifically [the section on defining routes](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/defining-your-routes/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Emberjs! first of all, I recommend you to visit the [official page](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/getting-started/first-app/) of Emberjs. Can you see the sidebar menu? well, be ready to spend some time reading it if you want to understand how Emberjs works. I strongly recommend you to read at least `Router, Template, Component and Controller` sections to begin with.

Let's see some of the snippets you have provided:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todos', { path: '/'}, function() {
    this.route('complete');
    this.route('incomplete');
  });
});
```

This is where you define your routes. Here what you have is the main route called 'todos' but used as the root page (starting at `/`). After it, there are two more routes: `/complete` and `/incomplete`.

```
model() {
    let todos = [
      {
        title: 'Learn Ember',
        complete: false,
      },
      {
        title: 'Solve World Hunger',
        complete: false,
      }
    ];
    return todos;
  }
```

Here you are defining a model in one route (I assume is the route of `todos`). Pretty straight, isn't it? if you were using `Ember Data` for example. you would ask the server for the model here and the route would wait until receive the response.

The reason why you have an `index` template and a `todos` template is simple: `todos.hbs` will contain the `{{outlet}}` in which every page will be rendered. Imagine it as a wrapper. Whatever comes after `/` will be wrapped by this `todos.hbs`, even the `index.hbs`. You have more info [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes), in the guides (reason why I recommend you to read it first).

Let's move to another snippet:

```
{{#todo-list todos=model}}
    {{outlet}}
{{/todo-list}}
```

Here you are using a `component` to wrap whatever is rendered in the `{{outlet}}`. You haven't pasted it here, but it should contain in its template at least a `{{yield}}` to specify where the `{{outlet}}` will be rendered. That info about `{{yield}}` can be found [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/).

Let's move to the next part:

```
ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each model as |todo|}}
         <!-- this loads the component todo-item and passes in a todo as todo -->
        {{todo-item todo=todo}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This `{{#each}}` handlebar, expressed in a block way (that's why it uses the `#` at the beginning and the `/` at the end), is a loop that allows you work with each item of your model, defined as `todo`. What you are doing here is to provide the component `todo-item` with one item of the model. If your model has 3 `todos`, `todo-item` will be rendered 3 times, one for each of them.

Again, I recommend you to follow that tutorial having the `emberjs guides` opened and whenever you have a doubt, check the guides until you understand the concept and then, move to the next step.

Comment: Awesome explanations. When you write: "todos.hbs will contain the {{outlet}} in which every page will be rendered. "... you mean the todos.hbs will wrap every page/url that is nested under the todos route inside the router.js right?

Comment: Exaclty :) whatever goes after `/` (remember that todo was assigned to the `/`) will be rendered there like `/complete`, `/incomplete`, `/list-of-todos/specific-todo`, etc.